# Stopping edge resize on click

Tags: window, resize

Ubuntu resizes a window with a single mouse click on the edge. I would really like to stop this behavior, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install CompizConfig Settings Manager

   ```
   sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager, type "ccsm" in the dash.
3. Locate:  Window Management → Resize Window
4. Uncheck the checkbox.

[image]

5. Try to resize the window, note that it no longer resizes on click.